# playing rtsp and loading images android phonegap (access origin )

Tags: android, cordova

i managed to play video through js in the folowing way:

`window.open('rtsp://<my-video-path>, '_system');`

by adding
   `<access origin=rstp://my-video-server-root/ </access>`

its playing.

the problem is that i loading images from another site, and when i add this line, the images are not loading.

if i add another line to the config.xml(before or after the rtsp line) :
  `<access origin="*" ></access>`

i can load the images but the video is not working(i get error: protocol not supported)

clearly there is colision between the lines.mybe i need to understand beter the way elcipse treats the  tags? where can i read more on this?

Comment: You wrote `rstp` instead of `rtsp`

Comment: Also I don't think the player supports rtsp

Answer (score 1):

It's been 5 months but if you didnt solve it or anybody has same problem this works for me;

Main problem is different protocols so i've changed access origin to

```
<access origin="*://*"/>
```

Using cordova 3.5.0